# Access both web.config and app.config from a single class

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

I need to read data from both app.config and web.config. My class will have read/write/update methods wrapped in a dll which will be used both by an application (exe) and by a web application. I need to make sure that i access the caller's default configuration file.

For app.config,

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager
    .OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

works fine.

What would be the equivalent code for web.config?

(P.S.: I read that

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager
    .OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)
```

works and some say that

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

would work. Which of these actually works and is more general? Or is there any other better alternative?

Comment: @DavidStratton Question edited. I'm looking to accessing these files on a frequent basis.

Comment: OK.  It's not possible to retract a vote to close, so I can't un-do my VTC.  However, IF this gets closed, you can flag it for reopening.